# if inside concat

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Here's the code I'm trying to use to create a trigger:

```
-- Dumping structure for trigger kavanga_lead.click_links_insert
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `click_links_insert`;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `click_links_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `click_links` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO actions_log 
        (
            `uid`,
            `table`,
            `action`,
            `new`
        )
        VALUES
        (  
            @user_id,
            'click_links',
            'insert',
            concat(NEW.id ,'|', NEW.`contents`, '|', NEW.channel_id, '|', NEW.name, '|', NEW.hidden, '|', if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id) '|', if(NEW.postfix_id is null,'',NEW.postfix_id))
        );
END//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
```

I keep getting an error (1583) `Incorrect parameters in the call to concat`.
It works well if I don't use `if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id)` but just a `NEW.prefix_id`. But this field can be `null`, so all `concat`'s result becomes `null` to.

So, the question is how can I use `IF` staments inside `CONCAT` call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's because you forgot one `comma` after `if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id)`  try:

```
concat(NEW.id ,'|', NEW.`contents`, '|', NEW.channel_id, '|', NEW.name, '|', NEW.hidden, '|', if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id), '|', if(NEW.postfix_id is null,'',NEW.postfix_id))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma after your `IF`. Once this is fixed, it would be better to use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) instead (or [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) if you prefer):

```
COALESCE(NEW.prefix_id,  '')
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is not valid because of the missing `comma` after your `inline IF` statement.

```
concat(NEW.id ,'|', NEW.`contents`, '|', 
       NEW.channel_id, '|', NEW.name, '|', NEW.hidden, '|', 
       if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id) '|', 
       --                                         ^ error here
       if(NEW.postfix_id is null,'',NEW.postfix_id))
```

it must be

```
concat(NEW.id ,'|', NEW.`contents`, '|', 
       NEW.channel_id, '|', NEW.name, '|', NEW.hidden, '|', 
       if(NEW.prefix_id is null,'',NEW.prefix_id), '|', 
       if(NEW.postfix_id is null,'',NEW.postfix_id))
```